# Why this become a list, when it's a dict key in python interpreter

Tags: python, json

I have a script to get data from a website, and to get all the data I need it hit 4 endpoints on that website, and for that I'm using python requests module.

But there's a strange bug in my code(and intrepretation) because I can't understand why this dict key, become a list, so throws the exception **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'** when the script handle with endpoint *'events'* in my code.

And the response that triggers the exception is like this:
**response.json() == {"endpoint":"events/1258594","doc":[{"event":"meeting_events","data":[]}]}**

On python interpreter no bugs(*response.json().get('doc')[0].get('data')*), but when i run this script it breaks:

```
def get_url(self, session, url):
    return session.get(url=url, headers=self.headers, timeout=30)


def get_data(self, res, endpoint, dir_json, dets):

    true = True
    false = False
    null = None

    if res.ok and res.status_code == 200:
        if len(res.text) < 350:
            print(res.text)

        data = res.json().get('doc')[0].get('data')
        if endpoint is 'events':
            print('data is: {}'.format(data)
            #data is: []

        menu = {'info': data.get('subject').get('data'),
                'events': data,
                'resume': data.get('events'),
                'details': data.get('index')
                }
        if menu.get(endpoint):
            self.save_file(os.path.join(dir_json, endpoint + '.txt'), res.json())
            dets.update({endpoint: True})
        else:
            dets.update({endpoint: False})
    return dets


def scrape_data(self, list_to_scrape):
    for x in list_to_scrape:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            endpoint_menu = ['info', 'events', 'resume', 'details']
            for endpoint in endpoint_menu:
                url_endpoint = getattr(self, endpoint)
                url_endpoint += str(x.data_id)

                response = self.get_url(session, url_endpoint)

                dets = self.get_data(response, endpoint, dir_json, dets)

                time.sleep(randint(4,6))
```

In the other endpoints, the key *'data'* returns a *dict*, but on *'events'* the key *'data'* returns a *list* with *dict's* inside when have data...

The question is, why the dict key *'data'* become a list index, trows that exception and how I can fix this?

Thanks for any support

Comment: ask a simple q pls

Comment: *"breaks"*? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: `Scrape_Json().scrape_data([SqlAlchemy_list])` endpoint **info** no bugs; endpoint **events** `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'` and the `requests response.json()` is `{"endpoint":"events/1258594","doc":[{"event":"meeting_events","data":[]}]}` sorry for not be so clear in my previous text

Comment: If i do\run `response.json().get('doc')[0].get('data')` in python intepreter no bugs, but breaks when I run this script. Any tips on this ?

Answer (score 0):

changed this:

```
menu = {'info': data.get('subject').get('data'),
            'events': data,
            'resume': data.get('events'),
            'details': data.get('index')
            }
if menu.get(endpoint):
```

to:

```
if endpoint is 'info':
    has_data = data.get('subject').get('data')
elif endpoint is 'events':
    has_data = data
elif endpoint is 'resume':
    has_data = data.get('events')
elif endpoint is 'details':
    has_data = data.get('index')

if has_data:
```